# Showing In proper Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

am Facing Problem with Kendo Grid,
I have place 4 Custom Buttons like
1.submit
2.approve
3.reject
4.cancel
and 2 are Default functions
1.edit
2.update

Here am Hiding and Showing the Buttons Based on the Status like Bellow

```
function HideEditButton()
    {
    var TravelPlanid = window.parent.Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();
     TravelPlanid = TravelPlanid.replace(/\{|\}/gi, '');
     var CreatedBy = null;
     if ( window.parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute("createdby")!=null && window.parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute("createdby")!=undefined)
     {
         CreatedBy = window.parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute("createdby").getValue()[0].id;
         CreatedBy = CreatedBy.replace(/\{|\}/gi, '');
     }

     var userId = Xrm.Page.context.getUserId();
    var userId = userId.replace(/\{|\}/gi, '');


     var grid = jQuery("#subdiv1").data("kendoGrid");
    var gridData = grid.dataSource.view();

        for (var i = 0; i < gridData.length; i++) {
            var currentUid = gridData[i].uid;
            console.log(i + ' ' + gridData[i].RecordType);

            if (gridData[i].pcl_travelplanactivitystatus.value == 798330003)
            {
                console.log("Model: " + i + ' ' + gridData[i].RecordType + " UID:" + currentUid);
                 var currenRow = grid.table.find("tr[data-uid='" + currentUid + "']");
                var submitButton = jQuery(currenRow).find(".k-grid-Submit");
                var editButton = jQuery(currenRow).find(".k-grid-edit");
                var deleteButton = jQuery(currenRow).find(".k-grid-delete");
                console.log(submitButton);
                console.log(editButton);
                console.log(deleteButton);
                deleteButton.hide();
                submitButton.hide();
                editButton.hide();
            }
            if (gridData[i].pcl_travelplanactivitystatus.value == 798330003 && CreatedBy == userId)
            {
                console.log("Model: " + i + ' ' + gridData[i].RecordType + " UID:" + currentUid);
                 var currenRow = grid.table.find("tr[data-uid='" + currentUid + "']");
                var approveButton = jQuery(currenRow).find(".k-grid-Approve");
                var rejectButton = jQuery(currenRow).find(".k-grid-Reject");
                console.log(approveButton);
                console.log(rejectButton);
                approveButton.hide();
                rejectButton.hide();
            }
            else if (gridData[i].pcl_travelplanactivitystatus.value == 798330000)
            {
                console.log("Model: " + i + ' ' + gridData[i].RecordType + " UID:" + currentUid);
                var currenRow = grid.table.find("tr[data-uid='" + currentUid + "']");
                var approveButton = jQuery(currenRow).find(".k-grid-Approve");
                var editButton = jQuery(currenRow).find(".k-grid-edit");
                var submitButton = jQuery(currenRow).find(".k-grid-Submit");
                var rejectButton = jQuery(currenRow).find(".k-grid-Reject");
                var deleteButton = jQuery(currenRow).find(".k-grid-delete");
                console.log(approveButton);
                console.log(deleteButton);
                console.log(editButton);
                console.log(rejectButton);
                approveButton.hide();
                editButton.hide();
                deleteButton.hide();
                submitButton.hide();
                rejectButton.hide();
            }

            else if (gridData[i].pcl_travelplanactivitystatus.value == 798330005 && CreatedBy != userId)
            {
                console.log("Model: " + i + ' ' + gridData[i].RecordType + " UID:" + currentUid);
                var currenRow = grid.table.find("tr[data-uid='" + currentUid + "']");
                var approveButton = jQuery(currenRow).find(".k-grid-Approve");
                var editButton = jQuery(currenRow).find(".k-grid-edit");
                var submitButton = jQuery(currenRow).find(".k-grid-Submit");
                var rejectButton = jQuery(currenRow).find(".k-grid-Reject");
                var deleteButton = jQuery(currenRow).find(".k-grid-delete");
                console.log(approveButton);
                console.log(deleteButton);
                console.log(editButton);
                console.log(rejectButton);
                approveButton.hide();
                editButton.hide();
                deleteButton.hide();
                submitButton.hide();
                rejectButton.hide();
            }
            else if (gridData[i].pcl_travelplanactivitystatus.value == 798330005 && CreatedBy == userId)
            {
                console.log("Model: " + i + ' ' + gridData[i].RecordType + " UID:" + currentUid);
                var currenRow = grid.table.find("tr[data-uid='" + currentUid + "']");
                var approveButton = jQuery(currenRow).find(".k-grid-Approve");
                var rejectButton = jQuery(currenRow).find(".k-grid-Reject");
                console.log(approveButton);
                console.log(rejectButton);
                approveButton.hide();
                rejectButton.hide();
            }
            else if (gridData[i].pcl_travelplanactivitystatus.value == 798330004)
            {
                console.log("Model: " + i + ' ' + gridData[i].RecordType + " UID:" + currentUid);
                var currenRow = grid.table.find("tr[data-uid='" + currentUid + "']");
                var approveButton = jQuery(currenRow).find(".k-grid-Approve");
                var editButton = jQuery(currenRow).find(".k-grid-edit");
                var submitButton = jQuery(currenRow).find(".k-grid-Submit");
                var rejectButton = jQuery(currenRow).find(".k-grid-Reject");
                var deleteButton = jQuery(currenRow).find(".k-grid-delete");
                console.log(approveButton);
                console.log(deleteButton);
                console.log(editButton);
                console.log(rejectButton);
                approveButton.hide();
                editButton.hide();
                deleteButton.hide();
                submitButton.hide();
                rejectButton.hide();
            }
            else if (gridData[i].pcl_travelplanactivitystatus.value == 1)
            {
                console.log("Model: " + i + ' ' + gridData[i].RecordType + " UID:" + currentUid);
                 var currenRow = grid.table.find("tr[data-uid='" + currentUid + "']");
                var submitButton = jQuery(currenRow).find(".k-grid-Submit");
                var editButton = jQuery(currenRow).find(".k-grid-edit");
                var deleteButton = jQuery(currenRow).find(".k-grid-delete");
                console.log(submitButton);
                console.log(editButton);
                console.log(deleteButton);
                deleteButton.hide();
                submitButton.hide();
                editButton.hide();
            }
            else if (gridData[i].pcl_travelplanactivitystatus.value == 798330002 && CreatedBy == userId)
            {
                console.log("Model: " + i + ' ' + gridData[i].RecordType + " UID:" + currentUid);
                var currenRow = grid.table.find("tr[data-uid='" + currentUid + "']");
                var approveButton = jQuery(currenRow).find(".k-grid-Approve");
                var editButton = jQuery(currenRow).find(".k-grid-edit");
                var submitButton = jQuery(currenRow).find(".k-grid-Submit");
                var rejectButton = jQuery(currenRow).find(".k-grid-Reject");
                var deleteButton = jQuery(currenRow).find(".k-grid-delete");
                console.log(approveButton);
                console.log(deleteButton);
                console.log(editButton);
                console.log(rejectButton);
                approveButton.hide();
                editButton.hide();
                deleteButton.hide();
                submitButton.hide();
                rejectButton.hide();
            }
             else  if (gridData[i].pcl_travelplanactivitystatus.value == 798330002 && CreatedBy != userId)
            {
            debugger;
                console.log("Model: " + i + ' ' + gridData[i].RecordType + " UID:" + currentUid);
                var currenRow = grid.table.find("tr[data-uid='" + currentUid + "']");
                var approveButton = jQuery(currenRow).find(".k-grid-Approve");
                var submitButton = jQuery(currenRow).find(".k-grid-Submit");
                var rejectButton = jQuery(currenRow).find(".k-grid-Reject");
                var deleteButton = jQuery(currenRow).find(".k-grid-Delete");
                console.log(approveButton);
                console.log(submitButton);
                console.log(rejectButton);
                console.log(deleteButton);
                deleteButton.hide();
                approveButton.hide();
                submitButton.hide();
                rejectButton.hide();
             }
             else  if (gridData[i].pcl_travelplanactivitystatus.value == 798330002 && CreatedBy != userId && gridData[i].pcl_managerremarks.value != null)
            {
            console.log("Model: " + i + ' ' + gridData[i].RecordType + " UID:" + currentUid);
                var currenRow = grid.table.find("tr[data-uid='" + currentUid + "']");
                var editButton = jQuery(currenRow).find(".k-grid-edit");
                console.log(editButton);
                editButton.hide();
             }



        }

    }
```

Here my Problem is if i clicked on Edit button i can able to Edit the Row Record but Here if i did not changed Record Values and I clicked on Update button then all buttons are showing

Comment: am Calling HideEditButton()  in edit function like edit: function (e) {
      
                            HideEditButton();
       
         
      var kendo = jQuery('input[id=activitystatus]').data("kendoDropDownList");
      kendo.select(1);
      kendo.readonly(!kendo.element.prop("readonly"));

    }

Comment: It is hard to understand your question. Can you try to reformulate it?